# Unable to click on a dropdown image of a IBM BPM listbox

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver, listbox

I am working on a IBM BPM portal which has the following drop down arrow next to a list box, requires a click to display list items in the DOM structure.

```js
<div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer dijitDownArrowButtonHover" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode">
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="image" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" alt="" src="/teamworks/script/coachNG/dojo/1.8.6/dojo/resources/blank.gif"/>
```

Image: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uud8f.jpg)

After clicking on the Image manually, following list items appears.

```js
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup_prev" class="dijitMenuItem dijitMenuPreviousButton" role="option" data-dojo-attach-point="previousButton" style="display: none;">Previous choices</div>
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup0" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="0">--- Select ---</div>
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup1" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="1">CJA Coversheet</div>
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup2" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="2">Correspondence</div>
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup3" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="3">Proof of Address</div>
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup4" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option" item="4">Proof of Identity</div>
<div id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1_popup_next" class="dijitMenuItem dijitMenuNextButton" role="option" data-dojo-attach-point="nextButton" style="display: none;">More choices</div>
```

I have tried following options to click on the image next to dropdown.

**Code1:**
 int xOffset = 0, yOffset = 0;
           Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
           WebElement TreeObj=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']/descendant::input[@type='image']"));
           actions.moveToElement(TreeObj, xOffset, yOffset);
           actions.moveToElement(TreeObj).click().build().perform();

**Code2:**
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']/descendant::input[@type='image']")).click();

**Code3:**
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='image'])[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uud8f.jpg)")).click();

Request others to investigate and help me clicking on the objects to select items from the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Drop down cannot be handled using normal action class or click method.
We need to use Select Class for it.

So just try out this..

```
Webelement someobject = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']/descendant::input[@type='image']"));

Select select = new Select(someobject);

someobject.selectByVisibleText("CJA Coversheet");
```

There are other methods also to select values from drop down, I am showing you visible text method..
Just try to run this. Hope it will help you..

Do go through this link. It is very helpful..

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-select-methods-to-work-with-dropdowns

Do reply whether it ran or not.
Happy Learning
:-)

Comment: //I have tried following option to verify the list items but in vain                                      WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']/descendant::input[@type='image']")); Select select = new Select(dropdown);  
          List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();  
          for(WebElement EachObj:options)  
          {  for (int i=0; i<exp.length; i++){
               if (EachObj.getText().equals(exp[i])){
               System.out.println("Matched");
               } } }

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could figure out a solution to perform actions on a BPM listbox. Thanks Kishan for spending some time,your suggestion might be useful for other web objects but not for BPM list boxes.

```js
String parameter = "--- Select ---;CJA Coversheet;Correspondence;Proof of Address;Proof of Identity"; 
           String[] splitparameter= parameter.split(";"); 
           
           WebElement fr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@dojoattachpoint='frame']"));
           driver.switchTo().frame(fr);
           
           //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='image'])[1]")).click();
           Thread.sleep(2000);
           
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dijit_form_FilteringSelect_0']")).clear();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dijit_form_FilteringSelect_0']")).sendKeys("CJA");
           
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']/descendant::input[@type='image']")).click();         
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']")).clear();      
                              
           WebElement TreeObj=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_1']/descendant::input[@type='image']"));
     //..................................................................................................................     
     int xOffset = 2, yOffset = 2;
     Actions actions = new Actions(driver);    
   actions.moveToElement(TreeObj, xOffset, yOffset).click().build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     List<WebElement> allListOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'FilteringSelect_1')]/descendant::div[contains(@id,'FilteringSelect') and @role='option' and @item>='0']"));

 //allListOptions.get(0).getText()
  for (int i = 0; i < splitparameter.length; i++) {      
   String optionValue = allListOptions.get(i).getText();
      if (optionValue.equals(splitparameter[i])) {            
          
       System.out.println("Value verified with the expected value: "+ optionValue);
      } else {            
          
       System.out.println("Failed to verify value with the expected value: "+ optionValue);
      }
   }
```